# Laravel change binding with Request params

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dependency-injection, service-provider

I am using `Laravel Framework 5.8.21`. I am trying to bind an `interface` to a class based on `Request` params inside `AppServiceProvider`'s `register` method like this.

```
public function register()
{
  $this->app->bind('App\Contracts\SomeInterface', 'App\Logic\ClassName');
  if(Request::has('notification_type') && Request::get('notification_type') == 'email') {
    $this->app->bind('App\Contracts\SomeInterface', 'App\Logic\SomeotherClassName');
  }
}
```

and later injecting the interface to `Controller`s `__construct()` method.

with tests, it always bound to `ClassName`. I tried to get accessed URL inside `AppServiceProvider` and while running `unit tests`, it always returning `/` with `$this->app->request->getRequestUri();` and method as `GET` even though from the test I am posting to URL like this.

```
$this->post('/notification', [
            'notification_type' => 'email',
  ])->assertJson(   
     'message-push-status' => true,
  ]);
```

While testing it with Postman, when I try to post `http://localhost:8000/notification`, it says, `419 | Page Expired.`

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. The **register** method of AppServiceProvider or any other service provider has access to **request parameters**.

This can be accessed as follows:

```
public function register()
{
  $this->app->bind('SomeInterface', function($app) {
    return new SomeClass(request()->some_parameter);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to reliably use the current request information from within a service provider.

First, it is a general best practice to not depend on application logic within the `register()` method directly. You may cause a race condition where you have a dependency that hasn't been registered yet, or cause unnecessary overhead (e.g. establish a database connection even if you don't need any querying).

Second, [Laravel's request lifecycle](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/lifecycle) won't funnel the current request into the application until *after* all of the service provider registration and bootstrapping has been completed.

Without knowing exactly what business logic you're trying to accomplish, you have at least a couple options:

1. Use [contextual binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container#contextual-binding) to serve different implementations of the same interface depending on the requesting object (e.g. controller).
2. Use a factory or a similar facilitator-style object that you can inject in the controller, and can provide the proper dependency based on your preferred logic.